# Google Analytics Reporting API "quota limit reached" despite not reaching quota

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I have a simple "most viewed" content script that has exceeded the daily quota limit for the Google Analytics reporting API, according to the 403 errors I am receiving.

Developer console shows the requests being made to the Analytics api quickly going from 200 to 403x:

[image]

But the Developer console also says I have ~50,000 daily request limit and have barely used 20% of my daily quota as shown here:

[image]

My question is:  Why is Google Analytics API giving me 10,000 request limit but also saying I have a 50,000 request limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your quota per **View** is 10K.

> The following quotas apply to all Reporting APIs, including the Core Reporting API v3, Analytics Reporting API v4, Realtime API v3, and Multi-channel Funnel API v3:
>
> - 10,000 requests per view (profile) per day (cannot be increased)
> - 10 concurrent requests per view (profile) (cannot be increased)

See: [Here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/limits-quotas)